# Completion of Bezout Domain a Bezout Domain?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Bezout domain, and $I$ any ideal inside of $R$. Is the $I$-adic completion
$$ \varprojlim_i R/I^i $$
necessarily a Bezout domain? If not, what conditions (on $R$ or $I$) might ensure that it is a Bezout domain?

Comment: To start with, it is not necessarily a domain: if you take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=6\mathbb{Z}$, the completion is $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$.